# jQuery ajax content type for IE with ajaxSubmit

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using the jQuery Form plugin to post forms. The response from the server is a json response.

At first it worked in all browsers except for IE. Now I got it working in IE by using `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"`.

But I have some forms with the ability to upload images. And in these forms IE is prompting to download as soon as I post the form.

How can I fix this?

The ajaxForm plugin suggested to use iframe: true but that was not my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The problem is de content type send back by the server.
I changed that to "text/html" and it worked in all browsers.

Not the best solution, but I'll take it for granted.
If someone knows a better solution involving sending back data from the server as 
"application/json" please keep me posted.